# Caching store that fetches all when a sort is requ

Tags: sorting, caching, dstore

I have a dgrid -> Cache store application to which I want to add sortable columns. The problem is that the REST provider cannot do the sorting, so I want any sort() request to trigger a fetch of the entire contents, and then further sorting and fetching to be done locally in memory.

In other words, before a sort is requested, I am happy for the Request store to query for the the desired ranges, but there cannon be rest queries passing sort keys to the server.

I have been mucking around with canCacheQuery, but I can't seem to get it to behave as required.

Can someone suggest a way to hook this up?